# Eclipse RCP Can't Contribute to Main Toolbar

Tags: eclipse-rcp, toolbar, perspective

My RCP app has the coolbar visible by setting `configurer.setShowCoolBar(true)` in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor#preWindowOpen`. But when I contribute a toolbar to the main toolbar, it never shows up. Here's my contribution code:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="true"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar id="toolbar.perspectivesDynamic">
            <dynamic
                  class="my.package.PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar"
                  id="perspectiveSwitcherToolbar">
            </dynamic>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

And the `ContributionItem` class:

```java
public class PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar extends ContributionItem {
    ...

    @Override
    public void fill(final ToolBar parent, int index) {
        //Does not get called
    }

    @Override
    public void fill(CoolBar parent, int index) {
        //Does not get called
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm using [this code](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/03/31/replacing-the-perspective-switcher-in-rcp-apps/) for adding a custom perspective switcher. It's rather old, but I see examples everywhere on the Internet adding a toolbar like this to the main toolbar, so I'm missing something elsewher, I assume

Answer (score 3):

I think that is [bug 392457](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392457): `<toolbar><dynamic></toolbar>` doesn't work at the moment. You can work around it by using a `<control>` and managing the contents yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented it per the workaround in the bug. It works except I can't get the toolbar to show updates. In the WorkbecnhWindowControlContribution's fill method, I create a Toolbar on the parent created in createControl. I fill the Toolbar successfully when the app loads. But later when I want to add an item to the Toolbar I call fill, I see that it adds the item, but the Toolbar doesn't show the new item until I relaunch the app. I tried calling update and layout on the Toolbar and its parent. Also called updateActionBars on the WorkbecnhWindow. How can I get the toolbar to update?